# Laravel - Getting count of nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have an application where users can control their properties and leases.

These are the relationships defined:

```php
//Team.php
/**
 * A team can have many properties.
 */
public function properties():
{
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}
```

```php
//Property.php
/**
 * A property can have many leases.
 */
public function leases():
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lease::class);
}
```

As you can see here, a Team can have many properties, and each property can also have many leases.

I am trying to figure out how I can get the number of leases that is associated with a Team:

```php
$team = Auth::user()->currentTeam;

return $team->properties->leases->count();
```

However, the above code returns an error:

> Property [leases] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: You're have to iterate `properties`; that's a Collection of `Property` instances, so calling `->properties->leases` won't work as it doesn't know which `property->leases` you're referencing. There's a `hasManyThrough()`, but it doesn't work for nested `many-to-many`, but `hasManyDepp()`, via [this package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) does.

Comment: @TimLewis After reading a bit more about `hasManyThrough` I do believe I can use it actually. (See my proposed answer)

Comment: Nice! I misread your question a bit, you don't quite have a nest `many-to-many` like I originally thought, you have nested `one-to-many` (one Team -> many Properties -> many Leases), so `hasManyThrough` should actually work just fine here. Glad you got it working regardless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a `hasManyThrough` relationship on the `Team` model, like so:

```php
//Team.php

/**
 * Get all of the leases for the team.
 */
public function leases()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Lease::class, Property::class);
}
```

Then I can simply get the number of leases created by a specific team by:

```php
return $team->leases()->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this method to your `Team.php`:

```
public function leasesCount(){
    return count(
        Team::
            join('properties', 'properties.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
            ->join('leases', 'leases.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
            ->where('teams.id', $this->id)
            ->get()
    );
}
```